# How to change value tbc of video with FFmpeg?

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I use **FFmpeg** to create video from one image with duration 10s and then cocat it with another video. The problem is the video shows glitches when play with default player of Android, but when i use **MX Player**, it only shows glitches in **HW decoder** mode, but not in **SW decoder** mode. I think it caused by value **tbc** is quite high.

Here is command i use to create video (named *test3.mp4*) from image:

```js
ffmpeg -loop 1 -t 10 -framerate 25 -i a03.jpg -f lavfi -t 10 -i anullsrc -vf scale=720:1280,setsar=1:1 -video_track_timescale 90k -ac 1 -c:a aac -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -strict experimental -y test3.mp4
```

Command concatenate it with video:

```html
ffmpeg -f concat -i file.txt -c copy -y out.mp4
```

*file.txt*:

```html
file 'test1.mp4'
file 'test3.mp4'
```

Video *test1.mp4*:

```html
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.46.101
  Duration: 00:00:36.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1512 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 1446 kb/s, 32.32 fps, 32 tbr, 90k tbn, 7143 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Video *test3.mp4*:

```html
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test3.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.46.101
  Duration: 00:00:10.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 543 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 536 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 1 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Video *out.mp4*:

```html
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.46.101
  Duration: 00:00:46.73, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1303 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 720x1280 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 1240 kb/s, 30.51 fps, 32 tbr, 90k tbn, 7143 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 54 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

Any suggestion? Thank a lot!

Comment: Does test1.mp4 play ok?

Comment: Yes, test1 and test3 play ok, but when i concatenate them, the output has problem

Comment: Then it won't be the tbc. test1 has the same high tbc.